# How to force set x ticks on matplotlib, or set datetime type with no year

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

So I have a function that will take a pandas dataframe and plot it, along with displaying some error metrics, and I also have a function that will take a pandas dataframe with a datetime type index, and take the daily average of the values in the dataframe. The problem is, when I try to plot the daily average, it looks really bad with matplotlib because it plots everyday as a seperate tick on the x axis. I have all this code in a package called Hydrostats, the github reposity source code for the daily average function is [here](https://github.com/waderoberts123/Hydrostats/blob/master/hydrostats/data.py), and the source code for the plotting function is [here](https://github.com/waderoberts123/Hydrostats/blob/master/hydrostats/visual.py). The plot for a linear time series is is below.
[image: Linear Time Series]
The Daily Average plot is shown below
[image: Daily Average Plot]

As you can see, you can't see any of the x axis ticks because they are all so squished together.

Comment: One needs a [mcve] of the issue, since such undesired behaviour may have many different reasons and we cannot guess here which one it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the ticks used for the x axis via [`ax.set_xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_ticks) and labels via [`ax.set_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html).

For instance you could just provide that method with a list of dates to use, such as every 20th value of the current `pd.DataFrame` index (`df.index[::20]`) and then set the formatting of the date string as below.

```
# Get the current axis
ax = plt.gca()

# Only label every 20th value
ticks_to_use = df.index[::20]

# Set format of labels (note year not excluded as requested)
labels = [ i.strftime("%-H:%M") for i in ticks_to_use ]

# Now set the ticks and labels
ax.set_xticks(ticks_to_use)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

**Notes**

If labels still overlap, you could also rotate the them by passing the rotatation argument (e.g. `ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)`).

There is a useful reference for time string formats here: http://strftime.org.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue with my plot

[image: plot shot]

Matplotlib automatically handles timestamps on axes, but only when they are in timestamp format. Timestamps in `index` were in string format, so I changed `read_csv` to

```
pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=[0], parse_dates=True)
```

Try changing the index to timestamp format. This solved the problem for me hope it does the same for you.

[image: nutha plot shot]