# X axis does not appear on pyplot figure

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to plot number of messages as function of time (Hour per day) Here is my code :

```
fig8 = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax8 = fig8.add_subplot()  
ax8.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=1))   #to get a tick every 15 minutes
ax8.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')) 
plt.plot(Central_group_mean['Hour'], Central_group_mean['Message'],'bo-')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The `Central_group_mean['Hour']` is a series of datetime which is the next:

```
0     00:00:00
1     01:00:00
2     02:00:00
3     03:00:00
4     04:00:00
5     05:00:00
........
22    22:00:00
23    23:00:00
```

The problem is: when I do a simple plot means : `plt.plot(Central_group_mean['Hour'], Central_group_mean['Message'],'bo-')` without ax8 setting it gives me the next figure:
[image]

While if I run the above scripts after setting ax8, I got the next pic :

[image]

What I need is the plot for each hour which already exists in `Central_group_mean['Hour']`

Comment: Did you try it without `ax8.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=1))`?

Comment: Sure it gave me the first figure but I want all the x axis to be plotted which is an interval of 24 hours

Comment: You want hourly ticks regardless of `Central_group_mean['Hour']` data or you want ticks for each item in `Central_group_mean['Hour']`?

Comment: I want all the values of Central_group_mean['Hour'] appear in x axis. As you see they already correspond to range of 24 hours

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force set x ticks on matplotlib, or set datetime type with no year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352482/how-to-force-set-x-ticks-on-matplotlib-or-set-datetime-type-with-no-year)

Comment: No it did not worked for me. I find another solution which is a bit simpler as I have in my x axis 24 values each one corresponding to an hour of the day